# smoking can cause cancer

Tags: modal-verbs

Does "can" mean possibility in these two sentences?

> You can get stamps from the local newsagents.

Perhaps you'll get stamps from the local newsagents. Perhaps not.

> Smoking can cause cancer

Maybe smoking causes cancer. Maybe not. We're not sure.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

These are different uses of *can*.

The first one means that the newsagent stocks stamps, so you *are able* to buy them there.

The second means that smoking is known to be one cause of cancer (but not all smokers are guaranteed to get it).